# 'Sum' : is not a member of 'Type<Object>' - C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

Writing this program for a class that should be able to create 4 class objects and use the template functions to call the arithmetic operations for different data types. My errors are telling me that my Sum, Difference, etc, functions are not members of the template class I created.

Here is my code for Type.h

```
#ifndef TYPE_H
#define TYPE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Object>
class Type : public Print
{
    public:
        //Constructor
        explicit Type(const Object & initValue = Object()) : storedValue(initValue){}

        //Accessor and Mutator for storedValue
        const Object & getValue() const;
        void setValue(const Object & val);

        //Additional Operations
        void Sum(const Type<Object> & val);
        void Difference(const Type<Object> & val);
        void Product(const Type<Object> & val);
        void Quotient(const Type<Object> & val);

    private:
        Object storedValue;
};

template <typename Object>
const Object & Type<Object>::getValue() const
{ return storedValue; }

template <typename Object>
void Type<Object>::setValue(const Object & val)
{ storedValue = val; }

template <typename Object>
void Type<Object>::Sum(const Type<Object> & val)
{ 
    cout << "The sum of " << val << "and " << storedValue << "is " << val += storedValue << endl; 
}

template <typename Object>
void Type<Object>::Difference(const Type<Object> & val)
{
    cout << "The difference of " << val << "and " << storedValue << "is " << val -= storedValue << endl;
}

template <typename Object>
void Type<Object>::Product(const Type<Object> & val)
{
    cout << "The product of " << val << "and " << storedValue << "is " << val *= storedValue << endl;
}

template <typename Object>
void Type<Object>::Quotient(const Type<Object> & val)
{
    cout << "The quotient of " << val << "and " << storedValue << "is " << val /= storedValue << endl;
}

class Print
{
    public:
        void printHello();
};

void Print::printHello()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}

#endif
```

Here is the code for TypeMain.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Type.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Starting with int operations
    Type<int> num1(3);
    Type<int> num2;

    num2.setValue(4);
    num2.Sum(num1);
    num2.Difference(num1);
    num2.Product(num1);
    num2.Quotient(num1);

    //Double operations
    Type<double> num3(3.3);
    Type<double> num4;

    num4.setValue(4.4);
    num4.Sum(num3);
    num4.Difference(num3);
    num4.Product(num3);
    num4.Quotient(num3);

    //Hello prints for each object
    num1.printHello();
    num2.printHello();
    num3.printHello();
    num4.printHello();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I've updated the code to what I've fixed. I no longer have errors with passing variables. I still however have the initial error where the functions are not members of Type

Comment: You have multiple function calls missing their arguments, those that do don't always have the correct arguments, you're trying to modify constant objects, and you have missing parenthesis around expressions.

Comment: Yes, I know about the calls. That part of the code isn't finished yet, I'm trying to fix the first error because I move on to that one.

Comment: You should create a [MCVE] so we can help you. I can't reproduce the problem, and I don't know if one of the other problems is really causing it.

Comment: I've corrected the function calls, and I'm still receiving the error.

Comment: There are more compiler errors now.

Comment: After adding in the parenthesis, removing the attempts to modify constant variables, and fixing the type mismatches, it compiles and runs. If you had tried to create a sample to demonstrate the problem, it would have fixed the problem.

Comment: Where am I missing parenthesis? As far as I can tell, I'm not missing any obvious ones..

Comment: Could you show me what you did to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra qualification `Type<Object>::` for member function declaration inside the class.

```
void /*Type<Object>::*/ Sum(const Object & val);
```

And `Sum` is supposed to take an `Object` (i.e. `int` for `Type<int>`), but you're passing a `Type<int>` to it, that's a mismatch.

Comment: Okay, I did this, but I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: @Sean I tried a minimal sample [here](http://rextester.com/NNYNH25237), what's the difference between it and your code?

Comment: @songyuanyao the difference is that your code does `Sum(1)` whereas his code does `Sum(num1)`

Comment: I've corrected the passing variables for all of the functions by changing (const Object ..) to (const Type<Object> ..) .. My code also matches your example, yet I'm still receiving the error. I'll update my code above to match the changes I've made.

Comment: @Sean If you changed the parameter's type, I think you have to change the implementation inside the function too.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1) Remove the `Type<Object>::` from the member function definitions in your header file.

2) In `main`, you do not call your functions with the correct parameter type.  For example:

```
Type<int> num1(3);
Type<int> num2;
num2.Sum(num1);
```

This is incorrect, as `Sum` is templated, so `Sum` has the following definition:

```
template <typename Object>
class Type : public Print
{
  ...
   void Sum(const Object& val);
};
```

Thus when instantiated, `Sum` is actually this:

```
   void Sum(const int& val);
```

So `Sum` takes a `const int&`, not a `Type<int>`

Comment: So should I change all of the (const Object ..) to (const Type<Object> ..) ?

Comment: @Sean Depends, do you want them to take an `Object` or a `Type<Object>`?

Comment: They should be taking Type<Object>'s. I've updated my code to show this.

Answer (score 0):

When you're declaring functions inside Type, you shouldn't prepend them with `Type<Object>::`. That is, your declaration for `setValue` should be `void setValue(const Object & val);`

Comment: Okay, I did this, but I'm still receiving the same error.